# How can we read device status in react native? (eg: phone in call , sleep mode, etc...)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I just need to read the status of the phone eg: in phone call /sleep mode etc ... is there any way to read all the status  ?

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#api) library which provides so much APIs to detect details of the mobile.

But to detect if user is in a call, you have to use another library such as [react-native-check-phone-call-status](https://github.com/torihuang/react-native-check-phone-call-status). I haven't used this library but worth to give a try.

Comment: can we check  whether  phone is in sleep mode?

Comment: and this( react-native-check-phone-call-status) is only for ios ?

Comment: With react--native-device-info you cannot find these. Either you have to find a package which satisfies your requirements or you have to write a native module. I prefer writing one because that will improve your knowledge as well. Isn't much harder as it seems.